# Best Practice of securing Google Cloud Run REST API

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-cloud-run

I have a REST API (implemented in Python) which is currently running on Google Cloud Run. I've configured it to:

- allow all traffic
- require authentication

and it currently it is working fine for me because I can log in (in the browser) with my google account (which has all required permissions). The problem which I am having is that I do not know (and cannot find) how to expose this REST API to a 3rd party back-end system. What I've tried so far is to create a global API Key which I want to pass in the request parameters but unfortunately that didn't work. I still get 403 error from Postman regardless if I pass the key or not.

I am aware that I can create a service account and grand it with `CloudRun.invoker` permission so it has permission to query my app but the only way I know to use it is via a `service_account_key.json` which doesn't work in my case as the client system doesn't implement any google-cloud functionality and it has to be rewritten.

If I could summarize - how to programatically authenticate to my Cloud Run application using a common technology as OAuth for example ?

More specifically - how do I impersonate a service account via OAuth or OAuth2.0 ?

Comment: Are your 3rd party system supports OAuth? Can they implement extra step to obtain a credential (no Google Cloud Libraries, only HTTP request and JSON handling)?

Comment: not really, I was just wondering how this can be done so it works with any 3rd party system out-of-the-box. Ideally the credentials should be passed in the request itself but the main idea is that google will authenticate the request, not the app running on cloud run, this is why I tried with API key first.Not sure if it is possible at all

Comment: You can use API gateway in front of Cloud Run. I wrote an article with ESPv2, but it's very similar to API gateway (which is managed ESPv2!). It should help you. https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I came across the cloud endpoints during my "research" but when I found out that they are deprecated by Google, I gave up on that path ...

`Cloud Endpoints Portal is being deprecated and will no longer be available after March 21, 2023. As part of the deprecation process, we will disable creation of new portals on April 21, 2022 `

so ... what is "the thing" now - Apigee ?

Comment: API gateway is a light Apigee. Apigee is a great solution, but a monster! (that eat lot of time to configure and money to run!). https://cloud.google.com/api-gateway

Comment: Put your reply for API Gateway as an answer so I can resolve the thread :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use API gateway in front of Cloud Run. I wrote an article with ESPv2, but it's very similar to API gateway (which is managed ESPv2!). It should help you. https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1

API gateway is a light Apigee. Apigee is a great solution, but a monster! (that eats lot of time to configure and money to run!). cloud.google.com/api-gateway